# LinkedList Java remove method

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

After using `remove` method, for some reason it doesn't add anything back to the linkedlist if you try to do so. Only happens after I call out `remove` method. Any ideas?

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements List<T>{

    private class Node<T> {
        T data;
        Node<T> next;
        Node( T data, Node<T> link) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = link;
        }
    }
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;
    private int size;


    public LinkedList()
    {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail=null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        var dd = new Node(item, null);
        if (head != null) {
            tail.next = dd;
            tail = dd;
        }
        else {
            head = dd;
            tail = dd;
        }
    @Override
    public boolean remove(T item) {

        if (head == null){
            return false;
        }
        // if it is in the start
        if (head.data.equals(item))
        {
            head = head.next;
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        Node<T>current = head;
        while(current.next != null)
        {
            if (current.next.data.equals((item))){
                current.next = current.next.next;
                size--;
                return true;
            }
            current=current.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Tried instead of formatting direct list doing backwards list and it all fixed. But my task is to do that in direct list version.

Comment: I strongly suggest you step through your code in a debugger, looking at the state carefully all the time.

Comment: And consider what `tail` points to if you remove the last item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function you could use to easily check the consistency of your list, since it has redundant information (`size`, `tail`) that needs to be kept in sync:

```
    public void print() {
        Node<T> current = head;
        Node<T> last = null;
        int counter = 0;
        while (current != null) {
            counter++;
            System.out.print(current.data);
            System.out.print(" ");
            last = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println("null");
        if (counter != size) System.out.println("size is inconsistent! " + counter + " != " + size);
        if (last != tail) System.out.println("tail is inconsistent!");
    }
```

Now when you use your implementation, for instance like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<>();
        lst.add(1);
        lst.print();
        lst.remove(1);
        lst.print();
    }
```

... You'll soon see that `size` and `tail` are not always kept in sync. After correcting errors, keep calling `print()` after every manipulation to see where the potentially next inconsistency occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you remove the last item in the list, then you need to move the `tail` pointer (one step towards head).

```
            ...
            if (current.next.data.equals(item)) { // your code
                if (current.next == tail) { // new code
                    tail = current; // new code
                } // new code
            ...
```

Also, your size variable should probably be removed. It is not used for anything and the way it is calculated makes no sense.